# Error Updating Packages (Error in Search for Dependencies)

Tags: fedora, upgrade

I was trying to do a routine package upgrade on Nobara 37 (Fedora 37), and I got this error. It's never popped up before.

```
Error in search for dependencies Problem: 

package opencv-contrib-4.6.0-7.fc37.i686 requires libClp.so.1, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mlt-7.12.0-4.fc37.i686 requires libopencv_tracking.so.406, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package coin-or-Clp-1.17.6-10.fc37.i686 requires libCbc.so.3, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libasl.so.3 needed by coin-or-Cbc-2.10.5-10.fc37.i686
```

I've tried to manually do a `sudo dnf install` on libclp.so.1 but it returned that it was already installed.

Any Takers?

Comment: Just curious, as it seems a bit unusual, do you really want/need the `i686` packages, or is there something preventing you from using the `x86_64` packages?

Comment: I'll be honest. I'm still learning linux since switching from windows. So, I was updating whatever was installed with the base distro. A couple x86_64 packages are giving the same error.

Comment: At least for the packages mentioned in the error message, there are `x86_64` packages available.  I would determine if you need any `i686` packages.  I'm not familiar with Nobara so I can't be certain which packages are required.  You could use `rpm -q --whatrequires the_package_name` to see which packages require that particular package.  If you do decide to remove some packages, be careful - `dnf` may want to _"autoremove"_ what it thinks are unneeded packages in addition to the ones you specify.  It doesn't always make the selection I want.

Comment: It's annoying and "untidy", but the error messages are only related to trying to upgrade some packages.  It doesn't mean something won't work on your system.  You'll get other error messages for that.  :-)